# jQuery / Arrow key is not triggering the keyup event

Tags: jquery, keyup

I am trying to use the right arrow key to change between classes but I am having problems with triggering the event with the arrow key. Instead it functions on mouse click. The right arrow key keyCode and which is 39. I have tried both and get the same result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(evt){
    console.log(evt.keyCode);// used to verify the keyCode 39

    if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
        $('body').toggle(function(){
            $('body').removeClass().addClass('narrow');

        }, function() {
        $('body').removeClass().addClass('large');

        }, function() {
        $('body').removeClass();
        });
        } 
        else {
        return false;
    };
    )
   });
```

Comment: Have you tried testing for `evt.which` instead of `.keyCode`?

Comment: Thanks for your response and yes I tried both and have used both but I get the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** --

Everything is correct, except the toggle.  Here is what I assume you are trying to do -

http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/nxJxj/3/

```
$(function() {

    $(document).keyup(function(evt) {

        if (evt.keyCode == 39) {

            if ($('body').hasClass('narrow')) {
                $('body').removeClass('narrow').addClass('large');
            } else if ($('body').hasClass('large')) {
                $('body').removeClass('large');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('narrow');
            }

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That works, thanks! Great, but I was under the impression that if there was no class named with .removeClass() that it would remove all classes. From http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/: "If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed." Any ideas on where I went wrong with the original code? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but why remove all classes, when you know which ones to remove? If you ever needed to add a class to it for general styling, then you'd be out of luck at that point, since it would be removed also :)  Just my two cents. **edit -- of course, you probably wouldn't run into that issue on the body, but just in general usage this is why I would not remove all classes.

Comment: True. Unfortunately due to my lack of reputation I am unable to give you any, but thanks again.

Comment: You just gave me rep by accepting this answer, so that is fine. :) Glad I could help!